# PHP MySQL logging issues

Tags: php

i have a simple login page(index.php) with username and password . I have created a file called db_connect.php which will have all the database related functions .

```
class Database{

    private $connection;
    private $db;

    function __construct()
    {

        $this->connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("cannot connect");  
        $this->db = mysql_select_db('logistics',$this->connection);
    }

    function verify_login($uid,$password)
    {
        $verify_login = "select user_id from log_users where user_login = '$uid' and user_password = '$password'";                  
        $status = mysql_query($verify_login,$this->connection);
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($status)){
        if($result['user_id'] == '1')
            {
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

Now i have created an object of the class database which is used to call the function verify_login($username,$password) . The problem here is the output is a blank page no matter what the status of the login is . It returns a resource id if i print the variable $status . But nothing is returned .

Comment: Where in the code should a message display if the login is successful? Do you know whether your function return true/false when appropiate?

Answer (score 0):

Amazing :)
sql injection ... No, I have not

```
or die("cannot connect");
```

use Exception and try/catch blocks

```
$verify_login = "select user_id from log_users where user_login = '$uid' and user_password = '$password'";
```

ohh. Why uid? uid is an integer value or string? if string name variable line u_login or something else with out id. But if it`s  integer... use (int) near $uid to get integer type of input data.
$user_passrord need to clean: mysql_real_escaping help us

```
$verify_login = "select user_id from log_users where user_login = '$uid' and user_password = 'mysql_real_escape_string($password)'";
```

than:

```
if(!empty($result)) {
    return true; // auth
}else{
    return false; // error auth
}
```

some_file.php:

```
// include your code

if(verify_login($login, $password)) {
    echo 'Auth!';
}
```